# How to turn off/reduce console output for PubNub iOS SDK 4.0?

Tags: ios, pubnub

PubNub iOS SDK 4.0 will generate lots of console outputs. Useful for developing the PubNub portion but crowd out the other console output.

How do I turn off/reduce the console output?

The following were tried but they don't work.

```
[PNLog enabled:NO]; 
[PNLog enableLogLevel:PNSilentLogLevel];
[PNLog setLogLevel:PNSilentLogLevel];
```

Comment: This is a known issue and the fix is planned for this week. We'll follow up with a answer on this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after the PubNub Objective-C update (version 4.0.2)

```
[PNLog setLogLevel:PNSilentLogLevel];
```

would work. Other available log level are defined in PNStructures.

Comment: Anybody has a Swift answer? Trying to do `PNLLogger.setLogLevel(PNLogLevel.PNSilentLogLevel)` but I get "Use of instance member 'setLogLevel' on type 'PNLLogger'; did you mean to use a value of type 'PNLLogger' instead?"

Comment: Same log level, slightly different API: `self.client.logger.setLogLevel(PNLogLevel.PNSilentLogLevel.rawValue)` - see API docs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: This worked for me: self.client.logger.setLogLevel(0)

Comment: Cool, that makes sense because `PNLogLevel.PNSilentLogLevel.r‌​awValue` is `0`